# Downloading file with Chrome WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have some data I need to get from a URL but the only way of doing so is via download. The code below works in certain instances of the specific website, but other times it opens the browser, navigates to the site, and then nothing. I've tried various instances of WebDriverWait but it doesn't seem to matter. I'm hoping someone can just help me pinpoint where the issue is because I'm pretty much lost.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

bs_url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search?hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7C&hfC=&hfSea=2016%7C&hfSit=&player_type=batter&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=L&batter_stands=&hfSA=&game_date_gt=&game_date_lt=&team=&position=&hfRO=&home_road=&hfFlag=&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_abs=0#results"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get(bs_url)
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
Stats = driver.find_element_by_id("table_all_pid_").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.quit()
```

HTML:

```
                >% of Pitches</th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>

                <th title="Create Chart Comparison" class="table-icon visual" id="compare_all_pid_"><img src="site-core/images/chart_curve.png" /></th>
                <th title="Download Results Comma Separated Values File" class="table-icon csv_table" id="table_all_pid_"><img src="site-core/images/disk.png" /></th>
                <th title="Download Data as Comma Separated Values File" class="table-icon csv" id="csv_all_pid_"><img src="site-core/images/database_link.png" /></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
```

Comment: Can you give details of what " it just won't download the file" means? Is there an error? Are you giving enough time after the click?

Comment: When I execute the script via powershell it gives me notice of DevTools listening, a Chrome browser opens and navigates to the site, and then it just sits there without downloading the file. I also tried removing driver.quit(), no change.

Comment: Can you share the relevant _HTML_ of the element `table_all_pid_` and around?

Comment: @DebanjanB Added

Comment: The thing you are clicking on is just a table header, not an actual link (odd they used headers but not my site). This means it has to be using JavaScript in some way to start the download. Try using a debug mode to step through your script and see if there are any js errors preventing the download from starting.

Comment: @MivaScott When I first started putting this script together that is what had me the most frustrated. I'm guessing they are purposely making it as difficult as possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

To click the element with title as **Download Results Comma Separated Values File** you can use the following code block :

- `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("th.table-icon.csv_table#table_all_pid_[title='Download Results Comma Separated Values File'] > img").click()
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@class='table-icon csv_table' and @id='table_all_pid_' and @title='Download Data as Comma Separated Values File']/img").click()
  ```